# Using two wildcards in CakePHP routing

Tags: routes, cakephp-2.0

So I have a bit of a tricky situation. I have a controller, `Joints`. It already has the following router connection:

```
Router::connect('/joints/*', array('controller'=>'joints', 'action'=>'view'));
```

The problem is now I'm building API methods to connect a mobile app, and that wildcard is way too aggressive! What I need to do is add something like the following, so I can send my API methods to the proper actions:

```
Router::connect('/joints/api{$method}', array('controller'=>'joints', "action"=>"api{$method}"));
```

Is there a way to leave my original wildcard, just cut inline when the action starts with "api"?

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Seems it was as simple as this:

```
Router::connect("/joints/:action/*", array('controller'=>'joints', "action" => ":action"));
Router::connect('/joints/*', array('controller'=>'joints', 'action'=>'view'));
```